# Problema con conexion de java a mysql

Tags: java, mysql

El problema reside al momento de conectar me tira un error, estoy trabajando con workbench 8.0.

Este es el código:

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
     Connection conexion = null;
     try {
        conexion = null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conexion =(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/escuela","root","1234");
        System.out.println("conexion establecida");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("error de conexion"+e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error de conexion "+e);
    }
      return conexion;
 }
```

y al momento de ejecutarlo me tira esta excepción:

> java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: El mensaje de error no se corresponde con el código de conexión, parece ser más bien un manejo de datos destinados a ser guardados en la base de datos. Verifica la línea exacta del error y el código que hay escrito en esa línea. ¿El mensaje `conexion establecida` no se muestra en la salida del sistema?